# finding maximum element in binary tree, its throwing error

Tags: python-3.x

```
def printMaxElementByLevelOrder(root):
    if not root:
        return
    queue =[]enter code here
    queue.append(root)
    maxElement = 0
    while(len(queue)>0):

        node = queue.pop(0)



        if maxElement < node.value 

        maxElement = node.value

        if node.left is not None:
            queue.append(node.left)
        if node.right is not None:
            queue.append(node.right)

    print maxElement
```

Comment: you can refer this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-minimum-element-in-a-binary-search-tree/

Comment: Thank you but i have already checked that approach, and i am not to solve errror of this code.

Comment: Also in geeksforgeeks, solution is about binary search tree and this program is for binary tree.

Comment: Okay I have never create binary tree in python but Let me try with the logic with C Language

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/binarytree/1.1.1

Comment: Thank You Tejas for your help

Comment: Happy to Help. :) Did you find your solution there ?

Comment: yeah,i realised that logic is correct,but syntax is wrong.In 9th line there should be ":" in the end of if statement, and the next line which is ->maxElement = node.value , should be inside that if statement

Comment: Ah okay... Thats good.

Comment: in 9th line:       if(maxElement < node.value): maxElement = node.value